# Passing parameters, pointer and adress problem

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing

I have some problem with passing parameters to function. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct VShop
{
    bool index;
    char *fName;
    char *edName;
    char *genre1;
    char *genre2; 
    double rating;
    double price;
};

void AddtoDB (VShop *Film, char *name, char *ed, char *genre1, char *genre2, double rating, double price, int *size, int *element);

int main()
{
    int size = 0, element = 0;
    VShop *Film = new VShop[size];

    AddtoDB(Film, "The Shawshank Redemption", "Frank Darabont", "Crime", "Drama", 9.2, 20, &size, &element);

    cout<<size; // ERROR!

    return 0;
}

void AddtoDB (VShop *Film, char *name, char *ed, char *genre1, char *genre2, double rating, double price, int *size, int *element)
{
    *size++;
    Film[*element].fName = name;
    Film[*element].edName = ed;
    Film[*element].genre1 = genre1;
    Film[*element].genre2 = genre2;
    Film[*element].rating = rating;
    Film[*element].price = price;
    *element=(*element+1);
}
```

Im getting error every time i wanna get `size` or `element`. What does it happen? Thanks.

Comment: An obvious error is that you are creating an empty pointer through `VShop *Film = new VShop[size]`. Since `size`==0, you don't allocate any memory at all (I'm not even sure that `new Foo[0]` is well defined). Why don't you use a vector for your database if you in any case are using C++?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Just need to rewrite my functtion. And i dont know anythind about vectors, because i just began to learn C++. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors with your code. Firstly:

```
VShop *Film = new VShop[size];
```

`size` is `0` and which may fail and will not work when you try to access it.

Secondly:

```
*size++;
```

`++` has higher precedence than `*` so it evaluates to:

```
*(size++);
```

while increments size and then dereferences the *old* value of size. You probably wanted:

```
(*size)++;
```

which increments the value of the `int` pointed to by `size`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a big problem with memory here. Look:

You created array with zero size:

```
VShop *Film = new VShop[size];
```

Then you try to grow up size **variable** but did not change array size:

```
*size++; //must be (*size)++;
```

Array still has zero length, but you are trying to change some data of first(zero) element:

```
Film[*element].fName = name;
```

You must resize array before inserting new element in it like that:

1. create new array with proper size;
2. copy all data from old array to new;
3. delete old array;
4. replace pointer to old array with new one.

Another variant is using std::vector.

Anyway, read some books about memory management in c++, and c++ at all.

Answer (score 0):

> Because ++ has greater precedence than *, this expression is
>   equivalent to *(size++). Therefore, what it does is to increase the value
>   of size (so it now points to the next element), but because ++ is used as
>   postfix the whole expression is evaluated as the value pointed by the
>   original reference (the address the pointer pointed to before being
>   increased).

Try using just;

```
(*size)++;
```

This will cause the expression to be evaluated as the value pointed by size increased by one.